# Does POSIX allow integers with padding bits?

Tags: c, posix

Can there be any POSIX compatible system where any integer type, except `_Bool`/`bool`, has padding bits?

Comment: What do you mean with pading bits?

Comment: The C standard allows it so why would POSIX restrict it?

Comment: [POSIX.1-2017 requires `CHAR_BIT` to be `8`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html#tag_13_23_03_06)

Comment: @Lundin Because it makes writing code easier. This would not be the only thing POSIX restricts, for example POSIX also restricts `CHAR_BIT` to be 8.

Comment: Just document that your program doesn't support fictional systems with one's complement, 16 bit bytes and EBCDIC. If it's important to someone to have compatibility with super-exotic, likely fictional systems, they can pay extra for it. It's a _feature_ that the code breaks if ported to super-exotic systems. The resulting head ache handed out to someone trying to port your code to such a system is suitable punishment for picking that system to begin with.

Comment: @kvantour As they are defined in C11 - 6.2.6.2 Integer types